# Dataframe replace underscore with blank not working

Tags: python, dataframe, replace

I'm struggling to work out why this replace is not working

Input Column Value

"Global Multi-Sector Income Composite(fka GITR) (USD) BWC_GMSI"

Expected Output

"Global Multi-Sector Income Composite(fka GITR) (USD) BWCGMSI"

**code**

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': ["Dummy", "Global Multi-Sector Income Composite(fka GITR) (USD) BWC_GMSI"], 'col2': ["dummy 3", "dummy4"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df2 = df.replace("_", "")
```

The result is not change....

Any ideas please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `regex=True`:

```
>>> df2 = df.replace(r"_", "", regex=True)
```

Otherwise, Pandas will search for exact matches, where the entire contents of the cell is a single underscore.

Example:

```
>>> d = {'col1': ["Dummy", "A_B__C_D"],
...      'col2': ["Dummy", "ABCD_"],
...      'col3': ["_", "_*_"]
...     }
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> df.replace(r"_", "", regex=True)
    col1   col2 col3
0  Dummy  Dummy     
1   ABCD   ABCD    *
```